# "Nested" relative frequency in 3 way flat contingecy table (ftable)

Tags: r, contingency

I am wondering whether there is a direct way to get nested relative frequencies in a 3-way flat (!) contingency table.

```
N    <- 10
(sex <- factor(sample(c("f", "m"), N, replace=TRUE)))
(work <- factor(sample(c("home", "office"), N, replace=TRUE)))
(satisfaction <- factor(sample(c("excellent", "ok","bad"), N, replace=TRUE)))
ftable(work, sex, satisfaction, row.vars=c("sex", "satisfaction"))
```

This code produces this output:

```
                work home office
sex satisfaction                 
f   bad                  1      1
    excellent            0      1
    ok                   1      1
m   bad                  1      0
    excellent            1      0
    ok                   1      2
```

What I would like to get is

```
                work home office
sex satisfaction                 
f   bad                  0.2      0.2
    excellent            0        0.2
    ok                   0.2      0.2
m   bad                  0.2      0
    excellent            0.2      0
    ok                   0.2      0.4
```

I am aware that i can calculate tables with prop.table but haven't figured out how this could be combined with flat contingency tables as produced by ftable. There is certainly a way to calculate the relative frequencies separately for each sex - group, but I am interested in a more direct way. 
So far I haven't found any way how to get relative frequencies into flat contingency tables.

Note: In this example male and female groups have the same size (5); however, the solution I am looking for should be flexible enough so that groups can also have different sizes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can consider starting with `table`, then using `prop.table` wrapped in `ftable`:

```
y <- table(sex, satisfaction, work)
y
# , , work = home
# 
#    satisfaction
# sex bad excellent ok
#   f   1         1  0
#   m   1         1  1
# 
# , , work = office
# 
#    satisfaction
# sex bad excellent ok
#   f   0         1  1
#   m   0         1  2

ftable(prop.table(y, margin=3))
#                  work home office
# sex satisfaction                 
# f   bad                0.2    0.0
#     excellent          0.2    0.2
#     ok                 0.0    0.2
# m   bad                0.2    0.0
#     excellent          0.2    0.2
#     ok                 0.2    0.4
```

This is assuming we start with something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 10
sex <- factor(sample(c("f", "m"), N, replace=TRUE))
work <- factor(sample(c("home", "office"), N, replace=TRUE))
satisfaction <- factor(sample(c("excellent", "ok","bad"), N, replace=TRUE))
```

---

Similarly, if you already have an `ftable` (let's call it "x"), you can try:

```
ftable(prop.table(as.table(x), margin=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
require("data.table")
dt <- data.table(sex,work,satisfaction)
dt2 <- dcast.data.table(dt,sex+satisfaction~work,value.var="satisfaction",fun=length)
dt2[,':=' (home=home/sum(home),office=office/sum(office))]
combs <- data.table(expand.grid(sex=levels(sex),satisfaction=levels(satisfaction)))
merge(combs,dt2,by=c("sex","satisfaction"),all.x=T)

#    sex satisfaction       home office
# 1:   f          bad 0.50000000    0.5
# 2:   f    excellent 0.16666667    0.0
# 3:   f           ok         NA     NA
# 4:   m          bad 0.08333333    0.0
# 5:   m    excellent 0.25000000    0.0
# 6:   m           ok 0.00000000    0.5
```